# What is the intended use of the optional "else" clause of the "try" statement in Python?

Tags: python, exception

What is the intended use of the optional `else` clause of the `try` statement?

Comment: Most answers seem to concentrate on why we can't just put the material in the else clause in the try clause itself. The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996329/ specifically asks why the else clause code cannot go *after* the try block itself, and that question is dupped to this one, but I do not see a clear reply to that question here. I feel https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996378/1503120 excellently answers that question. I have also tried to elucidate the various significance of the various clauses at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22579805/1503120.

Comment: You want something to occur if the exception doesn't trigger, before the final cleanup, that isn't ever supposed to itself trigger the same exception handling.

Comment: After forgetting what `else` does in `try/else` and `for/else` numerous times, I have mentally aliased it with `noexcept` and `nobreak` in those respective contexts. Personally I find it to be such an unfortunate overloading of the word that I try to avoid using it if I can, as it forces people reading code to wonder "what does this thing do again?" Usually a flag, a `continue` or `break` statement can relay what I'm trying to express with few extra lines, but certainly more clarity (if the popularity of the question is any indication).

Answer (score 1076, accepted):

The statements in the `else` block are executed if execution falls off the bottom of the `try` - if there was no exception. Honestly, I've never found a need.

However, [Handling Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) notes:

> The use of the else clause is better
>   than adding additional code to the try
>   clause because it avoids accidentally
>   catching an exception that wasn’t
>   raised by the code being protected by
>   the try ... except statement.

So, if you have a method that could, for example, throw an `IOError`, and you want to catch exceptions it raises, but there's something else you want to do if the first operation succeeds, and you *don't* want to catch an IOError from that operation, you might write something like this:

```py
try:
    operation_that_can_throw_ioerror()
except IOError:
    handle_the_exception_somehow()
else:
    # we don't want to catch the IOError if it's raised
    another_operation_that_can_throw_ioerror()
finally:
    something_we_always_need_to_do()
```

If you just put `another_operation_that_can_throw_ioerror()` after `operation_that_can_throw_ioerror`, the `except` would catch the second call's errors. And if you put it after the whole `try` block, it'll always be run, and not until after the `finally`. The `else` lets you make sure

1. the second operation's only run if there's no exception,
2. it's run before the `finally` block, and
3. any `IOError`s it raises aren't caught here

Comment: Also keep in mind that variables used in the try-block CAN be used in the else-block, so you should alway consider using this variant if you don't expect more exceptions in the else-block

Comment: That doesn't matter, because try-scoped variables are seen outside of the try whether there's an else or not.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "try-scoped variable". In Python, variable scopes are established only by modules, functions and comprehensions, not control structures.

Comment: The else clause lets you write code that only makes sense if an exception wasn't thrown; the except clause can simply pass. If you put the logic in the try block, you risk silently hiding bugs in your code. Never squash exceptions you didn't expect.

Comment: Actually my customer asked to log if the execution of a function was successful or not. In this case, `else` is very useful.

Comment: @BlairConrad : Why shouldn't we simply put something_we_always_need_to_do() inside the else: part ?

Comment: @mystikacid because the else clause is only executed if no exception was raised

Comment: it is not clear from this answer what the *"falls off the bottom"* means - not only does this happen because of an exception but also, because of a `return`, `continue` or `break`.

Comment: Actually, an error in the `else` block will be caught. Consider this... 
`try: x = 0` 
`except: print('foo')` 
`else: y = 1/0` 
`finally: print('bar')` 
Is there a way to suppress the division by zero error?

Comment: I have a use in django, when trying to search if a user with specified email exists:
`try:` `user = User.objects.get(email=email)` `except User.DoesNotExist:`
`user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)` `else:` `agent = Agent.objects.get(user=user)
        agent.is_active = True
        agent.save()`

Comment: I use `else:` to log successful execution in my `info.log` file.

Comment: If you want to play with the code from Blair Conrad go https://repl.it/@RuiCar/try-else

Comment: So you're telling me it's the same as not using the "else"... I say don't use it. Everyone who encounters try-else looks it up. Exception handling is the last place you want to play these games.

Comment: `else` essentially runs *after* the `try` block (if no exception occurs), but still *before* the `finally` block, which makes it different from either additional code at the end of the `try` block or code following the entire statement. (What I wonder is, why can't you have an `else` clause without any preceding `except` clause?)

Comment: @chepner, when you have no `except` clause, the `else` clause is exactly identical to putting it at the end of the `try` block. Unless you are putting that else with a except in mind (which you will write in future), it makes no sense.

Comment: @Sriram Not if you also have a `finally` clause: the `finally` clause will execute *after* `else`, but *before* the code following the entire `try` statement.

Comment: @chepner By "at the end of the `try` block" I meant putting whatever you were going to put in the `else` clause, inside `try` itself (equivalent to just commenting out the `else:` line). This will execute after your original `try` and before `finally`.

Comment: @Sriram But that code itself could raise an exception, which you may not want to catch or handle with the same code as the original code being `try`ed.

Comment: @chepner But you had originally asked in a case where there aren't any `except` clauses to catch errors in the first place. Think of `else` as a child of `except`, not the original `try`.

Comment: so from this answer, it seems like the `else` clause is totally not needed if you're not using the `finally` statement. Without `finally` statement one could just write whatever they need to write, outside the `try/except` clause. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 154):

There is one **big** reason to use `else` - style and readability.  It's generally a good idea to keep code that can cause exceptions near the code that deals with them.  For example, compare these:

```
try:
    from EasyDialogs import AskPassword
    # 20 other lines
    getpass = AskPassword
except ImportError:
    getpass = default_getpass
```

and

```
try:
    from EasyDialogs import AskPassword
except ImportError:
    getpass = default_getpass
else:
    # 20 other lines
    getpass = AskPassword
```

The second one is good when the `except` can't return early, or re-throw the exception.  If possible, I would have written:

```
try:
    from EasyDialogs import AskPassword
except ImportError:
    getpass = default_getpass
    return False  # or throw Exception('something more descriptive')

# 20 other lines
getpass = AskPassword
```

**Note:** Answer copied from recently-posted duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590146/why-use-pythons-else-clause-in-try-except-block/14590276#comment20366594_14590276), hence all this "AskPassword" stuff.

Answer (score 82):

> ## Python try-else
>
> What is the intended use of the optional `else` clause of the try statement?

The intended use is to have a context for more code to run if there were no exceptions where it was expected to be handled.

This context avoids accidentally handling errors you did not expect.

But it's important to understand the precise conditions that cause the else clause to run, because `return`, `continue`, and `break` can interrupt the control flow to `else`.

### In Summary

The `else` statement runs if there are *no* exceptions and if not interrupted by a `return`, `continue`, or `break` statement.

### The other answers miss that last part.

[From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

> The optional `else` clause is executed if and when control **flows off the
> end** of the `try` clause.*

(Bolding added.) And the footnote reads:

> *Currently, control “flows off the end” except in the case of an
> exception or the execution of a `return`, `continue`, or `break` statement.

It does require at least one preceding except clause ([see the grammar](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)). So it really isn't "try-else," it's "try-except-else(-finally)," with the `else` (and `finally`) being optional.

The [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) elaborates on the intended usage:

> The try ... except statement has an optional else clause, which, when
> present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that
> must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception. For
> example:

> ```
> for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
>     try:
>         f = open(arg, 'r')
>     except OSError:
>         print('cannot open', arg)
>     else:
>         print(arg, 'has', len(f.readlines()), 'lines')
>         f.close()
> ```
>
> The use of the else clause is better than adding additional code to
> the try clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception
> that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the try ... except
> statement.

## Example differentiating `else` versus code following the `try` block

If you handle an error, the `else` block will not run. For example:

```
def handle_error():
    try:
        raise RuntimeError('oops!')
    except RuntimeError as error:
        print('handled a RuntimeError, no big deal.')
    else:
        print('if this prints, we had no error!') # won't print!
    print('And now we have left the try block!')  # will print!
```

And now,

```
>>> handle_error()
handled a RuntimeError, no big deal.
And now we have left the try block!
```

Comment: main point from the docs: "The use of the `else` clause is better than adding additional code to the `try` clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the `try ... except` statement."

Comment: I think this is the best explanation. Thanks Aaron.

Comment: @starriet comment is clear and concise. Just wanted to highlight since this comment adds to this (already good) answer.

Comment: The example with the f=open() would explain more (at least to me) if the f.close() statement is in a "finally:" block.

Comment: That is an example quoted from the documentation - I'd rather present it as is...

Answer (score 68):

One use: test some code that should raise an exception.

```
try:
    this_should_raise_TypeError()
except TypeError:
    pass
except:
    assert False, "Raised the wrong exception type"
else:
    assert False, "Didn't raise any exception"
```

(This code should be abstracted into a more generic test in practice.)

Answer (score 31):

Try-except-else is great for combining [the EAFP pattern](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) with [duck-typing](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing):

```
try:
  cs = x.cleanupSet
except AttributeError:
  pass
else:
  for v in cs:
    v.cleanup()
```

You might think this naïve code is fine:

```
try:
  for v in x.cleanupSet:
    v.clenaup()
except AttributeError:
  pass
```

This is a great way of accidentally hiding severe bugs in your code. I typo-ed `cleanup` there, but the `AttributeError` that would let me know is being swallowed. Worse, what if I'd written it correctly, but the cleanup method was occasionally being passed a user type that had a misnamed attribute, causing it to silently fail half-way through and leave a file unclosed? Good luck debugging that one.

Answer (score 22):

I find it really useful when you've got cleanup to do that has to be done even if there's an exception:

```
try:
    data = something_that_can_go_wrong()
except Exception as e: # yes, I know that's a bad way to do it...
    handle_exception(e)
else:
    do_stuff(data)
finally:
    clean_up()
```

Comment: This is IMHO the best representation, an example using file I/O (shown somewhere above) illustrates this quite well. Basically, else: takes code out of the try: block and executes it before finally: if there was no exception, such as failing to open a file.

Answer (score 13):

Even though you can't think of a use of it right now, you can bet there has to be a use for it. Here is an unimaginative sample:

With `else`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
try:
    something = a[2]
except IndexError:
    print("out of bounds")
else:
    print(something)
```

Without `else`:

```
try:
    something = a[2]
except IndexError:
    print("out of bounds")

if "something" in locals():
    print(something)
```

Here you have the variable `something` defined if no error is thrown. You can remove this outside the `try` block, but then it requires some messy detection if a variable is defined.

Comment: What's wrong with `something = a[2]; print something` inside the try: block?

Comment: @ S.Lott nothing, but what if someone is sending you a list, and you don't want to display the data if its not long enough because it is probably corrupted?

Comment: S. Lott: 'print something' could raise a different exception that you don't want to intercept.

Comment: I don't see the difference.  If I get an out of bounds exception, it prints "out of bounds".  Got that.  If I get some other exception, it's uncaught by this block of code.  If I get no exception, the behavior is to print the value of something, which is a[2].  I don't see what the else does in this example.

Comment: The value of 'something', when printed, might raise the error in its __str__() method. While that value is actually just 2 in this example, you might just as well point out that there is no out-of-bounds exception here either.

Comment: For this (hypothetical) example, I would just put `something = 'out of bound'` in the except block so that `print(something)` would always print the correct response ;-)

Answer (score 11):

There's a nice example of `try-else` in [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#id9). Basically, it comes down to doing different exception handling in different parts of the algorithm.

It's something like this:

```
try:
    do_init_stuff()
except:
    handle_init_suff_execption()
else:
    try:
        do_middle_stuff()
    except:
        handle_middle_stuff_exception()
```

This allows you to write the exception handling code nearer to where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 8):

From [Errors and Exceptions # Handling exceptions - docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

> The `try ... except` statement has an optional `else` clause, which,
>   when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code
>   that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
>     try:
>         f = open(arg, 'r')
>     except IOError:
>         print 'cannot open', arg
>     else:
>         print arg, 'has', len(f.readlines()), 'lines'
>         f.close()
> ```
>
> The use of the else clause is better than adding additional code to
>   the try clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception
>   that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the try ... except
>   statement.

Answer (score 8):

```
try:
    statements # statements that can raise exceptions
except:
    statements # statements that will be executed to handle exceptions
else:
    statements # statements that will be executed if there is no exception
```

Example :

```
try:
    age=int(input('Enter your age: '))
except:
    print ('You have entered an invalid value.')
else:
    if age <= 21:
        print('You are not allowed to enter, you are too young.')
    else:
        print('Welcome, you are old enough.')
```

The Output :

```
>>> 
Enter your age: a
You have entered an invalid value.
>>> RESTART
>>> 
Enter your age: 25
Welcome, you are old enough.
>>> RESTART
>>> 
Enter your age: 13
You are not allowed to enter, you are too young.
>>>
```

Copied from : https://geek-university.com/python/the-try-except-else-statements/

Answer (score 6):

Looking at [Python reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html) it seems that `else` is executed after `try` when there's no exception.
The optional else clause is executed if and when control flows off the end of the try clause. [2](http://www.diveintopython.org/file_handling/index.html) Exceptions in the else clause are not handled by the preceding except clauses.

[Dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.org/file_handling/index.html) has an example where, if I understand correctly, in `try` block they try to import a module, when that fails you get exception and bind default but when it works you have an option to go into `else` block and bind what is required (see link for the example and explanation).

If you tried to do work in `catch` block it might throw another exception - I guess that's where the `else` block comes handy.

Comment: "The optional else clause is executed if and when control flows off the end of the try clause" is another difference, since you can return out of the `try` block.

Answer (score 4):

That's it. The 'else' block of a try-except clause exists for code that runs when (and only when) the tried operation succeeds. It can be used, and it can be abused.

```
try:
    fp= open("configuration_file", "rb")
except EnvironmentError:
    confdata= '' # it's ok if the file can't be opened
else:
    confdata= fp.read()
    fp.close()

# your code continues here
# working with (possibly empty) confdata
```

Personally, I like it and use it when appropriate. It semantically groups statements.

Answer (score 4):

I would add another use case that seems straight forward when handling DB sessions:

```
    # getting a DB connection 
    conn = db.engine.connect()

    # and binding to a DB session
    session = db.get_session(bind=conn)

    try:
        # we build the query to DB
        q = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.col1 == 'query_val')

        # i.e retrieve one row
        data_set = q.one_or_none()

        # return results
        return [{'col1': data_set.col1, 'col2': data_set.col2, ...}]

    except:
        # here we make sure to rollback the transaction, 
        # handy when we update stuff into DB
        session.rollback()
        raise

    else:
        # when no errors then we can commit DB changes
        session.commit()

    finally:
        # and finally we can close the session
        session.close()
```

Comment: Interesting - I know session.close() will be executed before the return, but will the session.commit() be executed? Does python recognize the "return" and delay that until else: and finally: are executed?

Comment: @user3481644 The order of execution would be:
- try block
- except block (in case of exception)
- else block (in case no exception)
- finally block at the end

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a use might be:

```
#debug = []

def debuglog(text, obj=None):
    " Simple little logger. "
    try:
        debug   # does global exist?
    except NameError:
        pass    # if not, don't even bother displaying
    except:
        print('Unknown cause. Debug debuglog().')
    else:
        # debug does exist.
        # Now test if you want to log this debug message
        # from caller "obj"
        try:
            if obj in debug:
                print(text)     # stdout
        except TypeError:
            print('The global "debug" flag should be an iterable.')
        except:
            print('Unknown cause. Debug debuglog().')

def myfunc():
    debuglog('Made it to myfunc()', myfunc)

debug = [myfunc,]
myfunc()
```

Maybe this will lead you too a use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another place where I like to use this pattern:

```
 while data in items:
     try
        data = json.loads(data)
     except ValueError as e:
        log error
     else:
        # work on the `data`
```

Comment: You can just use ``continue`` instead – the "break out early" pattern. This allows you to drop the "else" clause and its indentation, making the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the `try: ... else:` construct useful in the situation where you are running database queries and logging the results of those queries to a separate database of the same flavour/type. Let's say I have lots of worker threads all handling database queries submitted to a queue

```
#in a long running loop
try:
    query = queue.get()
    conn = connect_to_db(<main db>)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute("<some query on user input that may fail even if sanitized">)
    except DBError:
        logconn = connect_to_db(<logging db>)
        logcurs = logconn.cursor()
        logcurs.execute("<update in DB log with record of failed query")
        logcurs.close()
        logconn.close()
    else:

        #we can't put this in main try block because an error connecting
        #to the logging DB would be indistinguishable from an error in 
        #the mainquery 

        #We can't put this after the whole try: except: finally: block
        #because then we don't know if the query was successful or not

        logconn = connect_to_db(<logging db>)
        logcurs = logconn.cursor()
        logcurs.execute("<update in DB log with record of successful query")
        logcurs.close()
        logconn.close()
        #do something in response to successful query
except DBError:
    #This DBError is because of a problem with the logging database, but 
    #we can't let that crash the whole thread over what might be a
    #temporary network glitch
finally:
    curs.close()
    conn.close()
    #other cleanup if necessary like telling the queue the task is finished
```

Of course if you can distinguish between the possible exceptions that might be thrown, you don't have to use this, but if code reacting to a successful piece of code might throw the same exception as the successful piece, and you can't just let the second possible exception go, or return immediately on success (which would kill the thread in my case), then this does come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

An `else` block can often exist to complement functionality that occurs in every `except` block.

```
try:
    test_consistency(valuable_data)
except Except1:
    inconsistency_type = 1
except Except2:
    inconsistency_type = 2
except:
    # Something else is wrong
    raise
else:
    inconsistency_type = 0

"""
Process each individual inconsistency down here instead of
inside the except blocks. Use 0 to mean no inconsistency.
"""
```

In this case, `inconsistency_type` is set in each except block, so that behaviour is complemented in the no-error case in `else`.

Of course, I'm describing this as a pattern that may turn up in your own code someday. In this specific case, you just set `inconsistency_type` to 0 before the `try` block anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have found `else` useful for dealing with a possibly incorrect config file:

```
try:
    value, unit = cfg['lock'].split()
except ValueError:
    msg = 'lock monitoring config must consist of two words separated by white space'
    self.log('warn', msg)
else:
     # get on with lock monitoring if config is ok
```

An exception reading the `lock` config disables lock monitoring and ValueErrors log a helpful warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your programming logic depends on whether a dictionary has an entry with a given key. You can test the result of `dict.get(key)` using `if... else...` construct, or you can do:

```
try:
    val = dic[key]
except KeyError:
    do_some_stuff()
else:
    do_some_stuff_with_val(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the use scenarios I can think of is unpredictable exceptions, which can be circumvented if you try again. For instance, when the operations in try block involves random numbers:

```
while True:
    try:
        r = random.random()
        some_operation_that_fails_for_specific_r(r)
    except Exception:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

But if the exception can be predicted, you should always choose validation beforehand over an exception. However, not everything can be predicted, so this code pattern has its place.

Comment: You can do this putting the `break` inside the `try` at the end, which is cleaner IMO, and you don't need the `else`. Also the `continue` is not really needed, you can just `pass`.

Answer (score 0):

One could use this construct for handling exceptions in a common way within the `finally` clause, while doing something else when there's no exception:

```
class TooManyRetries(RuntimeError):
    pass


n_tries = 0
max_retries = 2
while True:
    try:
        n_tries += 1
        if n_tries >= max_retries:
            raise TooManyRetries
        fail_prone_operation()
    except Exception1 as ex:
        # handle1
    except Exception2 as ex:
        # handle2
    except Exception3 as ex:
        # handle3
    except TooManyRetries as ex:
        raise
    else: # No exception
        n_tries = 0
    finally:
        common_restore_state()
        continue
```

Answer (score -19):

The `else:` block is confusing and (nearly) useless.  It's also part of the `for` and `while` statements.

Actually, even on an `if`-statement, the `else:` can be abused in truly terrible ways creating bugs that are very hard to find.

Consider this.

```
   if a < 10:
       # condition stated explicitly
   elif a > 10 and b < 10:
       # condition confusing but at least explicit
   else:
       # Exactly what is true here?
       # Can be hard to reason out what condition is true
```

Think twice about `else:`.  It is generally a problem.  Avoid it except in an `if`-statement and even then consider documenting the `else`- condition to make it explicit.

Comment: I would disagree with this one.
In "if-elif" block, "else" is used as "default" would be used in "case" block of C language.
It is always recommended to handle "default" case even if you think you've covered all cases in various conditions.

Comment: @Josip: used as a "default" can be confusing.  The issue is to clearly define the condition that is this "default".  A poorly-defined default condition can be the root cause of buggy behavior.  Else can be a cause of confusion.  It should be thought through very carefully in all cases, not just try, for and while, but if as well.

Comment: Well, the above code is totally abstract and doesn't do anything meaningful, so yea - no wonder it is confusing.

Comment: @julkiewicz: The code is, sadly, very typical of a misused `else`.  I read a lot of code.  I've see this a lot.  What -- exactly -- is true for the `else`? It's rather hard to define correctly?

Comment: Sure this looks suspecious. It's just that for me it's not because of the `else` clause itself but because of the peculiar selection of conditions. You can write buggy code using whatever constructs you want pretty easily. It's not the constructs to blame.

Comment: @julkiewicz: "It's not the constructs to blame".  My point is that this is false.  If the `else` where not a part of the language, then the logic would have to be made absolutely explicit.  It would reduce the bugginess considerably by eliminating all guess-work on the part of you or I to try and determine of the `else` condition makes sense in the overall algorithm.  There's no place for guess-work or deduction.

Comment: @S.Lott "It would reduce bugginess" - and my point is that this is false. I think we just have a genuine difference in opinions. Bad programmers always find ways to write buggy programs. Always. Good programmers always seek good practices and can write good code in just about any language. Eliminating useful constructs just gives less power to the good programmers while not particularily helping out the bad ones as those are capable of inventing an infinite number of ways to f**k things up.

Comment: Consider: `if x > 0: return "yes"` and `if x <= 0: return "no"`. Now a person comes and changes one of the conditions to say `x > 1` but forgets to change the other one. How is that reducing number of bugs that would be committed. `if else` clauses are sometimes many lines apart. DRY is a good practice, much more often than not, really. (sorry for the double post).

Comment: @julkiewicz: If -- in your example -- a condition was omitted, it was omitted explicitly.  It requires little guess-work to read the `if` and `elif` blocks to prove that a condition was missing.  If we guess at the `else` block, we don't have any clear statement of the author's original design.  Just our personal guess.  It's hard to compare our guess as to the `else` condition with the author's, since the author left us no hint in the code.

Comment: I agree the `else` clause promotes less stringent efforts to account for all possible conditions. However I also propose that there are few actual real genii and therefore humans do miss conditions, even genii. I find the `else` clause a nice debug tool. If you have superpowers that catch all conditions everytime in your coding, perhaps you(noone in particular) can enjoy coding in C++ with all that lovely puncuation that stringent programmers never stumble on (or do they?). So my point is the use case is not if `else` promotes sloppiness, but if it deals with imperfection of human coders.

Comment: @DevPlayer: The imperfections in human coders are found **specifically** by avoiding `else` and dealing with the logic failures that show up.  No one is a genius.  Sloppy use of `else` makes it even harder to be  sure  things are right.    Avoiding `else` puts your human mistakes in your human face so you can fix them.  Not hope that something good happened.  The point is to have as many debugging tools (and diagnostic tools and human-imperfection detections) as possible.  Not **hope** that things will wok even when we stumble.

Comment: I agree with you @S.Lott that having debugging tools is a gain. I find the `else` clause a usable debugging tool. And I agree that using the `else` clause in some emotional **hope** is less logical then "dealing" with logic failures. However I disagree with that imperfections in human codes are found **specifically** by avoiding `else` clauses. It **may** help but it also **may** lead you to a false sense that you've avoided logic errors by omitting the `else`. Many mistakes go hidden simply because a test condition may be rarely encountered. Such rare occurances are not in one's face.

Comment: @DevPlayer: "it also may lead you to a false sense that you've avoided logic errors"  Unlikely.  Using `else: raise Exception('Logic Error')` is not a false sense of security.  It's a real failure that really happens and really reveals a logic error.  If your unit testing is not complete enough to find the logic error, then, production use will find it someday.  Using a lazy -- traditional -- "else-with-implied-condition" will not ever fail (even in production) and the logic error will remain hidden forever as a "weirdness" in the application.

Comment: For my money, worse than using `else` is `if a < 10`. The example given by @S.Lott is a 'straw man' for blaming `else`. What are `a` and `b`? As soon as you write `if batch_size < 10 ... elif batch_size >= 10 and job_size > 3 ... else ...` you know what you're reasoning about and there are fewer problems with `else`. Better still is to encapsulate the two conditions into variable names:  `is_small_batch = a < 10 ... is_huge_batch = a >= 10 and b > 3 ... if is_small_batch: ... elif is_huge_batch: ... else ...`. Other improvements, of course, are possible, some completely removing `else`.

Comment: you might, for example, use the chain of responsibility pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern but this is a sledgehammer to crack a walnut in many small cases. I have seen chain of responsibility make simple code obscure. IMO `else` can be completely appropriate in a well-defined case, and the `try...except...else` can occasionally express a problem more simply, eloquently and explicitly than any other structure.

Comment: You are totally off topic and 'else' is meant for executing logic that does not hold true for the conditions.