# when is it necessary to add an `else` clause to a try..except in Python?

Tags: python, exception

When I write code in Python with exception handling I can write code like:

```
try:
    some_code_that_can_cause_an_exception()
except:
    some_code_to_handle_exceptions()
else:
    code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions()
```

How does this differ from:

```
try:
    some_code_that_can_cause_an_exception()
except:
    some_code_to_handle_exceptions()

code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions()
```

In both cases `code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions()` will execute when there are no exceptions.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, in the second snippet, the last line executes always.

You probably meant

```
try:
    some_code_that_can_cause_an_exception()
    code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions()
except:
    some_code_to_handle_exceptions()
```

<strike>I believe you can use the `else` version if it makes the code more readable.</strike> You use the `else` variant if you don't want to catch exceptions from `code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions`.

Comment: Yes, the second snippet always executes, but there is more than a readability/stylistic difference between the first snippet and your sample.  In the first snippet, code_that_needs_to_run_where_there_are_no_exceptions() can never cause some_code_to_handle_exceptions() to run, whereas in your snippet it can.

Comment: David, you're right. As you can see, I realized it about 30 seconds before you posted your comment :)

Answer (score 9):

In the second example, `code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions()` will be ran when you **do** have an exception and then you handle it, continuing after the except.

so ...

In both cases code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions() will execute when there are no exceptions, but in the latter will execute when there are and are not exceptions.

Try this on your CLI

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def throws_ex( raise_it=True ):
        if raise_it:
                raise Exception("Handle me")

def do_more():
        print "doing more\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        print "Example 1\n"
        try:
                throws_ex()
        except Exception, e:
                # Handle it
                print "Handling Exception\n"
        else:
                print "No Exceptions\n"
                do_more()

        print "example 2\n"
        try:
                throws_ex()
        except Exception, e:
                print "Handling Exception\n"
        do_more()

        print "example 3\n"
        try:
                throws_ex(False)
        except Exception, e:
                print "Handling Exception\n"
        else:
                do_more()

        print "example 4\n"
        try:
                throws_ex(False)
        except Exception, e:
                print "Handling Exception\n"
        do_more()
```

It will output

> Example 1
>
> Handling Exception
>
> example 2
>
> Handling Exception
>
> doing more
>
> example 3
>
> doing more
>
> example 4
>
> doing more

You get the idea, **play around** with exceptions, bubbling and other things! Crack out the command-line and VIM!

Answer (score 6):

Example 1:

```
try:
    a()
    b()
except:
    c()
```

Here, `b()` will only be run if `a()` didn't throw, but the except block will also catch any exceptions that may be *thrown by `b()`*, which you might not want.  A general rule is: only catch exceptions that you know might happen (and have a way of handling).  Therefore, if you don't know whether `b()` will throw, or if you can't do anything useful by catching an exception thrown by `b()`, then *don't put `b()` in the `try:` block*.

Example 2:

```
try:
    a()
except:
    c()
else:
    b()
```

Here, `b()` will only be run if `a()` didn't throw, but any exceptions that `b()` throws will not be caught here and will continue to propagate up the stack.  This is very often what you want.

Example 3:

```
try:
    a()
except:
    c()

b()
```

Here, `b()` is always run, even if `a()` didn't throw anything.  This is also quite commonly useful, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You had the original code almost right.  Here's the full treatment:

```
try:
    some_code_that_can_cause_an_exception()
except:
    some_code_to_handle_exceptions()
else:
    code_that_needs_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions()

code_that_runs_whether_there_was_an_exception_or_not()
```

Comment: shouldn't `code_that_runs_whether_there_was_an_exception_or_not()` be in a finally block?

Answer (score 4):

While Ned Batchelder's response is appropriate for the OP, I'd like to slightly build upon it. Also, I can't reply as a comment to Mk12's comment (since I "only" have 49 rep, not 50, go figure). So my mite of contribution:

```
try:
    code_that_can_cause_an_exception()
except ParticularException:
    code_to_handle_the_particular_exception()
except:
    code_to_handle_all_other_exceptions()
else:
    code_to_run_when_there_are_no_exceptions_and_which_should_not_be_run_after_except_clauses()
finally:
    code_to_run_whether_there_was_an_exception_or_not_even_if_the_program_will_exit_from_the_try_block()

code_to_run_whether_there_was_an_exception_or_not_if_execution_reaches_here()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html)...

*"The optional else clause is executed if and when control flows off the end of the try clause.7.2 Exceptions in the else clause are not handled by the preceding except clauses."*

So look at this basic example as your answer

```
try:
  print("Try with Exception")
  print(sys.path)
except NameError:
  print "Exception"
else:
  print "Else"

print("Out of try/except block")

try:
  print("Try without Exception")
except NameError:
  print "Exception"
else:
  print "Else is now executed"

print("Out of try/except finally")
```

See how the else got executed when the exception didn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

I use try:..except:..else: a lot!

This is the pattern: try..except should span just one line of code where I anticipate an exception. Then except does the fallback/default handling, and else: does the thing I really wanted to do (no exceptions => go on to make what I wanted).

A simple example:

```
   # Exhibit 1
   data_paths = []
   try:
       from . import version_subst
   except ImportError:
       first_datadir = "./data"
   else:
       first_datadir = os.path.join(version_subst.DATADIR, PACKAGE_NAME)


# Exhibit 2
for attr in attrs:
    try:
        obj = getattr(plugin, attr)
    except AttributeError, e:
        if warn:
            pretty.print_info(__name__, "Plugin %s: %s" % (plugin_name, e))
        yield None
    else:
        yield obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using Python for all that long, but I try to handle specific exceptions in a `try` block, and use `else` to handle the "other" exceptions I might not have expected, similar to a `default` block in C/C++ `switch` blocks.  Is that an appropriate use for `else` as well?

Comment: Ignore my above post-doesn't work that way at all.  Back to the books for me!