# else clause in try statement... what is it good for

Tags: python, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python try-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else)

Comming from a Java background, I don't quite get what the `else` clause is good for.

According to the docs

> It is useful for code that must be
>   executed if the try clause does not
>   raise an exception.

But why not put the code after the try block? It seems im missing something important here...

Comment: This issue has been discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else

Comment: While many people have tagged this as a dup of the above question, it doesn't really seem to address the difference the OP asks about here i.e. between putting *after* the try block and within the else clause. AndrewBC's reply below answers that much better. My contribution http://stackoverflow.com/a/22579805/1503120 may also be useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `else` clause is useful specifically because you then know that the code in the `try` suite was successful. For instance:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        f = open(arg, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print 'cannot open', arg
    else:
        print arg, 'has', len(f.readlines()), 'lines'
        f.close()
```

You can perform operations on `f` safely, because you know that its assignment succeeded. If the code was simply after the try ... except, you may not have an `f`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider

```
try:
    a = 1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "Division by zero not allowed."
else:
    print "In this universe, division by zero is allowed."
```

What would happen if you put the second `print` outside of the `try/except/else` block?

Comment: It's also better than putting it after the assignment to `a`, before the `except` —which would be equivalent to this example— because it prevents catching of unwanted exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

It is for code you want to execute *only* when no exception was raised.