# Is it important to use an "else" block after an "except" block?

Tags: python

I know [what a `try-else` block is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else), but consider the following two functions:

```
# Without else
def number_of_foos1(x):
    try:
       number = x['foo_count']
    except:
       return 0
    return number

# With else
def number_of_foos2(x):
    try:
       number = x['foo_count']
    except:
       return 0
    else:
       return number

x_with_foo = dict(foo_count=5)
x_without_foo = 3
```

Unlike [this `try-else` question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14590146/2071807) we're not adding extra lines to the `try` block. In both cases the `try` block is a single line, and the principle of keeping error handling "close" to the errors that caused it is not violated.

The difference is in where we go *after* the successful `try` block.

In the first block, the code continues after the `except` block, and in the second, the code continues at the `else`.

They obviously give the same output:

```
In [138]: number_of_foos1(x_with_foo)
Out[139]: 5

In [140]: number_of_foos1(x_without_foo)
Out[140]: 0

In [141]: number_of_foos2(x_with_foo)
Out[141]: 5

In [142]: number_of_foos2(x_without_foo)
Out[142]: 0
```

Is either preferred? Are they even any different as far as the interpreter is concerned? Should you *always* have an `else` when continuing after a successful `try` or is it OK just to carry on unindented, as in `number_of_foos1`?

Comment: in your case, you're returning from except block. So it is equivalent. What if you didn't return? that wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python try-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else)

Comment: I *think* this question is slightly different to the proposed dupes. I'll try and explain how, and see how that goes. (Maybe it's not really different!)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, yes I think that's the crucial distinction here, isn't it? Because the except block always returns, the else block is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the case where you enter in the exception block must be *rare* (that's what we call that an *exception*). So using `else` gives too much importance to that block, which isn't supposed to happen in normal operation.

So if an exception occurs, handle the error and return, and forget about it.

Using `else` here add more complexity, and you can confirm this by disassembling both functions:

```
>>> dis.dis(number_of_foos1)
  4           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            14 (to 17)

  5           3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo_count')
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (number)
             13 POP_BLOCK
             14 JUMP_FORWARD            12 (to 29)

  6     >>   17 POP_TOP
             18 POP_TOP
             19 POP_TOP

  7          20 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
             24 POP_EXCEPT
             25 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 29)
             28 END_FINALLY

  8     >>   29 LOAD_FAST                1 (number)
             32 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(number_of_foos2)
 <exactly the same beginning then:>

 15          20 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             23 RETURN_VALUE

             24 POP_EXCEPT
             25 JUMP_FORWARD             5 (to 33)
             28 END_FINALLY

 17     >>   29 LOAD_FAST                1 (number)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

As you see in the second example, addresses 24, 25, 28, 33 and 36 aren't reachable, that's because Python inserts jumps to the end of the code, and also a default `return None` in the main branch. All this code is useless, and would vouch for snippet #1 which is simpler and returns the result in the main branch.