# Why use else in try/except construct in Python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I am learning Python and have stumbled upon a concept I can't readily digest:  the optional `else` block within the `try` construct.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> The try ... except statement has an optional else clause, which, when
>   present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that
>   must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

What I am confused about is why have the **code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception** within the try construct -- why not simply have it follow the try/except at the same indentation level?  I think it would simplify the options for exception handling.  Or another way to ask would be what the code that is in the `else` block would do that would not be done if it were simply following the try statement, independent of it.  Maybe I am missing something, do enlighten me.

This question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else) but I could not find there what I am looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `else` block is only executed if the code in the `try` doesn't raise an exception; if you put the code outside of the `else` block, it'd happen regardless of exceptions. Also, it happens before the `finally`, which is generally important.

This is generally useful when you have a brief setup or verification section that may error, followed by a block where you use the resources you set up in which you don't want to hide errors. You can't put the code in the `try` because errors may go to `except` clauses when you want them to propagate. You can't put it outside of the construct, because the resources definitely aren't available there, either because setup failed or because the `finally` tore everything down. Thus, you have an `else` block.

Comment: ah, OK ...  makes perfect sense.  so why not put it at the end of the try section then ?  is it because of the possibility that that code itself is throwing the exception and you want to limit the scope of the exception origin?

Comment: Yup. It's common practice to put it in the `try` in other languages, especially if there is no `except` block, but in Python, we have `else`, so we use that.

Comment: also it allows you to return from within try and have the return line throw an exception, or not :D

Answer (score 4):

One use case can be to prevent users from defining a flag variable to check whether any exception was raised or not(as we do in `for-else` loop).

A simple example:

```
lis = range(100)
ind = 50
try:
    lis[ind]
except:
    pass
else:
    #Run this statement only if the exception was not raised
    print "The index was okay:",ind 

ind = 101

try:
    lis[ind]
except:
    pass
print "The index was okay:",ind  # this gets executes regardless of the exception

# This one is similar to the first example, but a `flag` variable
# is required to check whether the exception was raised or not.

ind = 10
try:
    print lis[ind]
    flag = True
except:
    pass

if flag:
    print "The index was okay:",ind
```

**Output:**

```
The index was okay: 50
The index was okay: 101
The index was okay: 10
```