# Why isn't the code in the `else` section of my `try` block being run?

Tags: python, json, exception, flask

I'm using Python 2.7.3 with Flask 0.10.1 and SQL-Alchemy 0.9.1.

In my view code, I'm building an object for database input, and my code depends on the proper execution of two `try`/`except`/`else` blocks. It works as expected for the first block, both when exceptions occur and when they do not. When there's an exception, I get a collection of `errors`. When there's not an exception, the data get added to the database and the sample counter increments. Here's that snippet:

```
        try:
            new_sample = Sample()
            new_sample.build(sample)
        except SampleBuildingError as e:
            result_response['errors'].append('{0}: {1}'.format(sample['sample_name'], e.value) )
        else:
            db.session.add(new_sample)
            num_added += 1
```

Further down in the view function, I have a `try`/`except`/`else`/`finally` block. The data are being committed to the database, so the `try` portion is clearly working, as is the `finally` block. However, it appears that the `else` block is not being executed:

```
try:
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    result_response['error'] = "Failed on the database input: {0}".format( str(e) )
else:
    result_response['success'] = "The samples were input to the database successfully. {0} samples entered into the database, with {1} errors".format( num_added, len(errors) )
finally:
    return jsonify(result_response)
```

When there's an exception, I get json back with an `error` key and the database error, as expected. However, when the database commit is succesfully, I get a json object with every expected key **except** the `success` key.

It appears that the `else` block is being skipped, but I can't figure out why. I've tried putting the word `bogus` in the second line of the else block to try to force an error, but Python doesn't complain!

Here's the full view function:

```
@app.route("/kapasubmit", methods=['POST'])
def kapasubmit():
    num_added = 0
    result_response = {'errors': []}
    samples = request.json['data']
    for sample in samples:
        sample_check = Sample.query.filter_by( sample_name = sample['sample_name'] ).first()
        if sample_check is None:
            try:
                new_sample = Sample()
                new_sample.build(sample)
            except SampleBuildingError as e:
                result_response['errors'].append('{0}: {1}'.format(sample['sample_name'], e.value) )
            else:
                db.session.add(new_sample)
                num_added += 1
        else:
            result_response['errors'].append('{0}: This is a duplicate sample'.format(sample['sample_name']) )

    if num_added > 0:
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            result_response['error'] = "Failed on the database input: {0}".format( str(e) )
        else:
            result_response['success'] = "The samples were input to the database successfully. {0} samples entered into the database, with {1} errors".format( num_added, len(errors) )
            bogus
        finally:
            return jsonify(result_response)
    else:
        result_response['error'] = "No valid samples submitted for input"
        return jsonify(result_response)
```

Comment: I have made a quick test, `>>> try:
...     pass
... except:
...     pass
... else:
...     print 'else'
... finally:
...     print 'finally'
... 
else
finally
` This seems to work. There has to be something else.

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah, it's puzzling as all get-out, because the first statement works exactly as it should. The second statement works except that it skips the else block. Baffling, especially to a Python (but not coding) newbie.

Comment: In this particular case, why not just put the statement into the try block. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else the only time you need the else is when there is an exception raising case that you do not want to be handled by your except: In this case the else is not needed.

Comment: `len(errors)`: I don't see where `errors` is defined?

Comment: @sabbahillel That's a good suggestion. But now I'm wondering what's up, just for my knowledge.

Comment: @njzk2 I think you're on to something! I neglected to fix that after a refactor. That could be the source of the problem!

Comment: @njzk2 I fixed that bug and tested it, but it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: that has to be it. put a try except around your `.format` call and log stuff (also, if you put a log in the else block right after the else, i'm quite confident you'll see it)

Comment: At first I would have thought that the indentation might have linked the else to the preceding if but I see that you have an else for that if so you would have gotten a syntax error. What happens if you dummy the code to remove the first try except block. Do you still get the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `errors` is not defined.

`len(errors)` would raise an exception, but not prevent the execution of the `finally` block, hence still returning some data, without having defined `result_response['success']`

Comment: Thanks: I tested this with else: print 'in else', errors, 'out of else' finally: 'done' and the 'in else' 'done' got printed followed by the NameError errors not defined output.

Comment: typo in the above comment, each string should have a separate print for it to be undestandable you might want to add a code snippet to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 3):

In case `else` block raises an exception, it gets ignored, since the interpreter has to execute `return` from the function.  A demo:

```
>>> def divide(x, y):
...     try:
...         result = x / y
...     except ZeroDivisionError:
...         print "division by zero!"
...     else:
...         print "result is", result
...         print 1/0
...     finally:
...         return 1
... 
>>> divide(2,1)
result is 2
1
```

`1/0` doesn't cause any traceback.

Comment: that makes the use of `return` and `finally` quite dangerous, as there is no reason the result would be any different if there was an exception raised in the except block as well.

Comment: This is correct and helpful, thanks! @njzk2 spotted the error first, so I think I have to give him the check.