# filtering through a list using for loops and conditionals

Tags: python

Using Python 2.7. I have the following list inside of a list:

```
 channels = [[ch1a.twist, ch1b.twist, ch1c.twist, ch2a.bop, ch2b.bop, ch3c.pull]]
 new_list = []
```

I want to apply the following logic to my code:

- check to see if the 'a' version of the channel exists. If it does then append to new_list
- if the 'a' version does not exist, then check for the 'b' version of the channel and append to new_list
- if the 'a' or 'b' version do not exist, then check for the 'c' verison of the channel and append to new_list

I would like to run the for loop such that

```
channels = [...]
new_list = []
for "blah":
   do stuff

print new_list
>> new_list = [ch1a.twist, ch2a.bop, ch3c.pull]
```

So far I have

```
 for list in channels:
    for ch in list:
        try: 
            prefix, suffix = ch.split('.')
        except ValueError:
            pass 
        else:
            if 'a' in prefix:
                new_list.append(ch)
            elif 'b' in prefix:
                new_list.append(ch)
```

but this is still returning the ch1a.twist and the ch1b.twist...grrrrrr. I thought 'elif' was supposed to mimic the following logic: 'else if previous condition was not met then execute the following'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but the logic is probably closer to  'else if previous condition was not met **but this one is** then execute the following'

Comment: Is the issue perhaps with [Python try-else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else)?

Comment: your first comment is correct. is there documentation that talks about this?

Comment: Yes, for example [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) and official documentation that will be drier to read. But I actually think my second comment is more relevant overall tbh. Why do you have `try`/`else`?

Comment: When I try to do `channels = [[ch1a.twist, ch1b.twist, ch1c.twist, ch2a.bop, ch2b.bop, ch3c.pull]]` I get `NameError: name 'ch1a' is not defined`. Are those supposed to be strings or something?

Comment: Are different versions of a channel always grouped together, or is it possible for something like `ch1a.twist, ch2a.bop, ch1b.twist` to occur? Are the versions of a channel always in alphabetical order, or is it possible for something like `ch2b.twist, ch2a.twist` to occur? Are channels always the letters "ch" followed by a single digit followed by a single character between 'a' and 'c'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error as @roganjosh, so I've assumed that your list-within-a-list should contain strings (it's a simple enough change if they're not).

The main issue with your provided code is that if you ever hit the code to check whether 'b' is in the prefix, then you are never looking to see whether you've already added the channel number to `new_list`.

The easiest way I've found to modify your code is as follows (it's not pretty, but I was trying to keep your code as un-touched as possible):

Firstly, sort the list-within-a-list using `channels[0].sort()`

Next, track which channel number you have already added by initialising a list using `channelNumbers = []`

Next, I split the prefix so that I separate the channel number from the channel version:

`channelNumber = prefix[:-1]
channelVersion = prefix[-1:]`

Finally, I tweak your `elif` statements so that they only add the b- or c- versions if the channel number hasn't already been added:
`elif 'b' in prefix and not channelNumber in channelNumbers:`
and `elif 'c' in prefix and not channelNumber in channelNumbers:`

So the full code becomes:

```
channels = [['ch1a.twist', 'ch1b.twist', 'ch1c.twist', 'ch2a.bop', 'ch2b.bop', 'ch3c.pull']]
new_list = []
channelNumbers = []
channels[0].sort()

for list in channels:
    for ch in list:
        try:
            prefix, suffix = ch.split('.')
            channelNumber = prefix[:-1]
            channelVersion = prefix[-1:]
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if channelVersion == 'a':
                new_list.append(ch)
                channelNumbers.append(channelNumber)
            elif channelVersion == 'b' and not channelNumber in channelNumbers:
                new_list.append(ch)
            elif channelVersion == 'c' and not channelNumber in channelNumbers:
                new_list.append(ch)

print(new_list)
```

And the output is, as you requested: `['ch1a.twist', 'ch2a.bop', 'ch3c.pull']`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- you intended for `ch1a.twist` et al to be string literals, and just forgot the quote marks
- `channels` contains exactly one list
- All the versions of a channel are next to one another in the list
- The versions are in alphabetical order (so, say, "ch1b" never comes before "ch1a")

Then you can use `groupby` to group the items by channel name, and extract the first occurrence of each channel using `next`.

```
import itertools
def channel_name(channel):
    prefix, suffix = channel.split(".")
    return prefix[:-1]
channels = [["ch1a.twist", "ch1b.twist", "ch1c.twist", "ch2a.bop", "ch2b.bop", "ch3c.pull"]]
result = [next(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(channels[0], key=channel_name)]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['ch1a.twist', 'ch2a.bop', 'ch3c.pull']
```