# Print statement is not working in try catch else finally block

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Try Catch Else Finally block to create this function.

Here is my code:

```
def read_a_file():
    """
    >>> out = read_a_file() #while the file is not there
    The file is not there.
    We did something.
    >>> print(out)
    None
    >>> Path('myfile.txt').touch()
    >>> out = read_a_file() #while the file is there
    The file is there!
    We did something.
    >>> type(out)
    <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
    >>> out.close()
    >>> os.remove("myfile.txt")
    """
    try:
        file_handle = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
        return file_handle
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('The file is not there.')
        return None
    else:
        print('The file is there!')
    finally:
        print('We did something.')
```

However, when I run the doctest, the print statement never work in except and else block. Only the print statement in finally block is working.

I got this as result, which is not what I wanted.

```
>>> out = read_a_file() #while the file is not there
We did something.
```

Help!!! How to solve this issue?

You have to import these packages

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
from pathlib import Path
import os
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Python 3.6.3

Comment: Sounds to me like the file *is* there, perhaps because a previous doctest failed before it would have deleted the file.

Comment: I ran your code on python 3.6.0 it works as expected

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `doctest`.  The behavior is expected because, when you `return`, the `else:` clause is *not* executed.  From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> The optional else clause is executed if and when control flows off the end of the try clause. [2]
>
> ...
>
> [2] Currently, control “flows off the end” except in the case of an exception or the execution of a return, continue, or break statement.

So if you want `The file is there!`to appear if and only if no exception is raised, lose the `else:` clause and move

```
print('The file is there!')
```

above

```
return file_handle
```

Comment: Surely you mean move `print('The file is there!')` to above `return file_handle` in the try-clause? Better to show how the code should look.