# What is the most idiomatic alternative to Python's try…catch…else in Dart?

Tags: python, exception, dart

Coming from Python, I really miss the `else` clause in the `try-except` chains in Dart.

What's the most idiomatic to simulate the `else` clause in Dart?

---

Here is an example that benefits from an `else` block.

This:

```
var didFail = false;
try {
    startDownload()
} catch (e) {
    didFail = true;
    downloadFailed()
}   
if (!didFail) {
    downloadSuccess()
}    
afterDownload()
```

vs:

```
try {
    startDownload()
} catch (e) {
    downloadFailed()
} else {
    downloadSuccess()    
}
afterDownload()
```

Comment: Put the code from `else` at the end of the `try` block, before the `catch`? Not 100% the same, but maybe close enough.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need the `else`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else

I always find myself needing one.

Comment: There are certainly some cases where it's nice to have it, but _need_ it? Probably not. Can you show some example?

Comment: This question isn't a discussion of whether this should be included in the language. I ask what's the most idiomatic way to handle the case when a try-catch block might just use a `return` statement, and never execute the code after it.

Comment: There's also the obvious case where some piece of code only gets executed when absolutely no exception occurs, which is the main reason for having an `else` block.

Comment: I did not want to discuss that, but it will be much easier to provide an answer if we have an example of the `try/catch/else` code you want to replicate. For example, I see no problem of putting that "absolutely no exception occurred" code at the very end of the `try` block.

Comment: Does the `try / on exception catch / on exception catch / catch` syntax not work for you? See the catch section of the Language Tour https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#catch

Comment: @jessi `catch` catches any exceptions not already caught previously; Python's `else` clause executes if there *were* no exceptions.

Comment: @tobias_k Done.

Comment: @DevAggarwal The example should probably include a `finally` block as well, to capture precisely when the `else` clause gets executed. (Or, just see my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: my entire experience with Dart is the 2 minutes I just spent reviewing the syntax of its `try` statement. This is based solely on a observation about Python's semantics.

---

### What does `else` do in Python?

Skip to the end of the answer for the suggested Dart code.

The following two pieces of code are very similar in Python:

```
try:
    ...
    <last code>
except SomeError:
    ...
finally:
    ...
```

and

```
try:
    ...
except SomeError:
    ...
else:
    <last code>
finally:
    ...
```

`<last code>` will be executed in the same circumstances in both. The difference is that any exceptions raised by `<last statement>` will be caught in the first, but not in the second.

### Simulating `else` in Python

To simulate `else`'s semantics in Python, you would use an additional `try` statement and a flag to indicate if an exception should be rethrown.

```
else_exception = False
try:
    ...
    try:
        <last code>
    except Exception as e:
        else_exception = True
except SomeError:
    ...
finally:
    if else_exception:
        raise e
    ...
```

We check if the nested `try` caught an exception in the `finally` clause, since the `else` clause would have executed before anything else in `finally`. If there was an exception, reraise it now that it won't be immediately caught, just as in the `else`. Then you can proceed with the rest of `finally`.

---

### Simulating `else` in Dart

As far as I can tell, the same logic would be necessary in Dart.

```
bool else_exception = false;
try {
  ...
  try {
     <last code>
  } catch (e) {
    else_exception = true;
  }
} on SomeError catch (e) {
  ...
} finally {
  if (else_exception) {
    throw e;
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that if `<last code>` throws an exception, the above code will *not* properly preserve the stacktrace.  To do that, some more care would be needed:

```
bool else_exception = false;
try {
  ...
  try {
     <last code>
  } catch (e) {
    else_exception = true;
    rethrow;
  }
} on SomeError catch (e) {
  if (else_exception) {
     rethrow;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: (Posting as a community wiki because I fully expect my Dart code to need some correction.)

Comment: Nice one. I guess in my case I didn't need those two nested blocks, since I wanted to catch _all_ exceptions.

Comment: Note that in Python, there is a difference between `except` and `except Exception`. Usually, you just use `except Exception` and handling things like `SystemExit` explicitly, if at all. I don't know if Dart has anything similar in its exception handling code.

Comment: @chepner The original transformation you gave won't preserve the stacktrace from exceptions thrown by the `else` block.  I've modified your answer to try to deal with that, although it's significantly uglier (one reason is that `rethrow` is valid only within a `catch` block).

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, you should just be able to write whatever goes into the `else` block directly at the very end of the `try` block. There may be [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/855759/1639625) where the `else` block is useful, and can provide somewhat clearer or more expressive code, but you can, e.g., write your code much more compact than what you did in your "no else" example as

```
try {
    start_download() // exception?
    // yay, no exception
    download_success()
} catch (e) { // preferrably "on KindOfException catch (e)"
    download_failed()        
}
afterDownload()
```

It may not be as explicit that `download_success` only executes if there was no exception, but *implicitly* it is clear, because *if* there *were* an exception, the `try` block would have been aborted and the execution would have gone into the `catch` block.

*Of course*, this also means that exceptions raised in `download_success()` will also go to the `catch` block. This may be prevented by using a more specific exception, e.g. `on VeryBadDownloadException catch (e)`, assuming that `start_download` and `download_success` will not raise *exactly the same* kinds of exceptions.

Comment: That `catch` block will catch any exceptions occurred in the `download_success()` routine. That can lead to a lot of unintended behaviour. It's not a matter of explicitness, but code correctness.

Comment: This would also run `download_failed` even if the download succeeded, but `download_success` raised an exception. I know you said this would work in *most* cases, but I think it's important to point out when it would *not*.

Comment: @DevAggarwal See, that's why I wanted to have an example, preferrably with some description _why_ you think an `else` would help there. From just the code and your comments, it did not seem like `download_success` would raise an exceptoin, much less the same kind of exception as `start_download` would.