# What's wrong with " except Exception as e"

Tags: python, exception, except

I got the following error for my code.
Can anyone help me pls.

code is as follows

```
def askforinteger():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("enter an integer")
        except Exception as e :
            print("there is a error of", e)
        else:
            print("person has entered correct input")
            break
        finally:
            print("clsoe this issue")
```

Error is as follows

```
  File "<ipython-input-5-234fd49c196d>", line 5
    except Exception as e :
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Format your question properly. No one can help you if your code is not even readable.

Comment: You should add a language tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have error syntax :

you forget to add  bracket in **a** attribute

hope this will fix it
try this out :

```
  def askforinteger(): 
        while True: 
            try: 
                a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
                print("person has entered correct input") 
            except Exception as e : 
                print("there is a error of", e)     
                break 
            finally: 
                        print("clsoe this issue")
```

Comment: "first else only came with if statement", see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else

Comment: @Omkar76 thanks didn't know , i edit answer