# Tips For an Intro Python Program

Tags: python

Below is my first python program. I am trying idea not yet covered in class as i hate staying stagnant and want to solve issues that may arise if i were to just use the info we've learned in class. As for my question, the program works but what were be ways to condense the code, if any? Thanks!

```
#This is a program to provide an itemized receipt for a campsite
# CONSTANTS
ELECTRICITY=10.00 #one time electricity charge

class colors:
    ERROR = "\033[91m"
    END = "\033[0m"


#input validation 
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            nightly_rate=float(input("Enter the Basic Nightly Rate:$"))
        except ValueError:
            print(colors.ERROR +"ERROR: Please Enter the Dollar Amount"+colors.END)
        else:
            break
    while True:
        try:
            number_of_nights=int(input("Enter the Number of Nights You Will Be Staying:"))
        except ValueError:
            print(colors.ERROR +"ERROR: Please Enter a Number"+colors.END)
        else:
            break
    while True:
        try:
            campers=int(input("Enter the Number of Campers:"))
        except ValueError:
            print(colors.ERROR +"ERROR: Please Enter a Number"+colors.END)  
        else:  
            break
    break
#processing         
while True:
    try:
        campsite=nightly_rate*number_of_nights              
        tax=(ELECTRICITY*0.07)+(campsite*0.07)
        ranger=(campsite+ELECTRICITY+tax)*0.15 #gratuity paid towards Ranger
        total=campsite+ELECTRICITY+tax+ranger  #total paid per camper
        total_per=total/campers
    except ZeroDivisionError:                  #attempt to work around ZeroDivisionError
        total_per=0                            #total per set to zero as the user inputed 0 for number-
    break                                          #-of campers

#Output     #Cant figure out how to get only the output colored
print("Nightly Rate-----------------------",nightly_rate)
print("Number of Nights-------------------",number_of_nights)
print("Number of Campers------------------",campers)
print()
print("Campsite--------------------------- $%4.2f"%campsite)
print("Electricity------------------------ $%4.2f"%ELECTRICITY)
print("Tax-------------------------------- $%4.2f"%tax)
print("Ranger----------------------------- $%4.2f"%ranger)
print("Total------------------------------ $%4.2f"%total)
print()
print("Cost Per Camper-------------------  $%4.2f"%total_per)
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might want to read: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can remove both the outer `while` loops, as `break` is seen there at the top level, so the loops runs once only.
2. You can convert `colors` to an Enum class if desired (this is more of a stylistic choice tbh)
3. The line `tax=(ELECTRICITY*0.07)+(campsite*0.07)` can be represented as `x*0.07 + y*0.07`, which can be simplified to `0.07(x+y`) or `0.07 * (ELECTRICITY + campsite)` in this case.
4. Instead of manually padding the `-` characters in the `print` statements, you can use f-strings with simple [formatting trick](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-pad-fill-string-by-variable-python).
   For example, try this out:

```py
width = 40
fill = '-'
tax = 1.2345

print(f'{"Tax":{fill}<{width}} ${tax:4.2f}')
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The `else` in `try` statement is unnecessary. You can just put the `break` in the the end of the `try` statement. [REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else)
2. In the end, in the `print` statements, I recommend you to use another types of formatting. You can use `'...{}..'.format(..)` or further pythonic is `f'...{val}'`. Your method is the oldest. [More ref](https://medium.com/@mark.tripney/formatting-large-numbers-in-python-a90b8266dee)