# What is the correct purpose of else block in try--except-else-finally in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning Python. I have a fundamental doubt about the "try--except--else--finally" statement sequence.

As I understand if code in 'try' goes through then code in 'else' will also get executed. If that is the case, what is the need for 'else' block? Whatever code is under 'else' block can be in 'try' block itself.

Appreciate clarifications

Answer (score 2):

`Else` block gets executed when `try` block raises no error.
`Except` block gets executed when `try` raises an error.
`finally` block gets executed regardless of whether `try` raises an error or not

[Docs about it can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

The process goes on this way:

1. `try` section is executed normally
2. if there's error (exception) raised, it goes to the `except` block
3. if there's no error raised in `try` section, then `else` block will be executed
4. then comes `finally` block. `finally` is independent of exceptions. It is executed always

Comment: I have found the explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else

Comment: @Srinivas ok, I didn't know you got the answer. I had answered it 10 hours ago and you got the answer 1 hour ago 