# how to throw an error if certain condition evaluates to true

Tags: python-3.x

I have below code block:

```
try:
    if str(symbol.args[0]) != str(expr.args[0]):
        print('true')
        raise SyntaxError('====error')
except:
    pass
```

Here I am trying to raise `Syntax error` if certain condition is true.I am testing this code block, I can see 'true' is getting printed which means condition is met but even after that also the code is not throwing syntax error.

I am trying to understand what is wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting **pass** in the **except:** block which is swallowing the exception. Either remove the code from the try-except block or change **pass** to **raise**

Comment: If all the `except` block contains is a `raise`, there's no point in having try/except in the first place.

Comment: Correct, but if he did decide to act on the error he would have to raise the exception again instead of pass so just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is pointing the issue, I just want to give some examples to help you better understand how `try/except` works:

```
# Just raise an exception (no try/except is needed)
if 1 != 2:
    raise ValueError("Values do not match")

# Catch an exception and handle it
a = "1"
b = 2
try:
    a += b
except TypeError:
    print("Cannot add an int to a str")

# Catch an exception, do something about it and re-raise it
a = "1"
b = 2
try:
    a += b
except TypeError:
    print("Got to add an int to a str. I'm re-raising the exception")
    raise
```

`try/except` can also be followed by `else` and `finally`, you can check more about these here: [try-except-else-finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127613/what-is-the-correct-purpose-of-else-block-in-try-except-else-finally-in-python/70127644)