# else block not invoked when there is no exception in wrapped function

Tags: python, python-decorators, try-except

In below code, when there is no exception raised from `bar`, I am expecting the `else` block of decorator to be called, but this is not happening.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from functools import wraps

def handle_exceptions(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        try:
            errorFlag = True
            print("error flag set as true")
            return func(*arg, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            raise
        else:
            print("else block hit")
            errorFlag = False
        finally:
            if errorFlag:
                print("Error seen in finally")
    return wrapper

def bar():
    pass

@handle_exceptions
def foo():
    bar()


foo()
```

Output when `bar` does not raise any exceptions:

```
error flag set as true
Error seen in finally
```

Why is `print("else block hit")` missing here?

Comment: The `else:` block is not hit because you have `return` inside `try:`, so only `finally:` is executed.

Comment: in the try clock you are returning

Comment: Here's a good explanation to your try, except, else https://stackoverflow.com/a/28443901/977593

Comment: @Andrej Kesely 
 Thanks! "The else statement runs if there are no exceptions and _if not interrupted by a return_, continue, or break statement."

Answer (score -2):

A similar try - else, exception handling code to get inspired from:

```
    try:
        # Code that may raise an exception
        x = 5 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # Handle the exception
        print("Division by zero is not allowed")
    else:
        # Execute if no exception is raised
        print("Division was successful")
    finally:
        # Always execute, regardless of an exception
        print("This will always be executed")
```

Because your **try** block had no errors or exceptions and you are using **return**, you code will simply skip the **else** condition.

Comment: *"Because there was no exception in your try, it simply skipped the else condition."* Are you saying that the `else` condition is run when an exception **is** raised?

Comment: @TkrA As mentioned in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html, else condition should be ran when exception is *not* raised. "The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception."

Comment: @m.divya.mohan yes but also *"The optional else clause is executed if the control flow leaves the try suite, no exception was raised, **and no return, continue, or break statement was executed**."* https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#else-clause